# How can I print the sum of the elements in a 2-D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is what I currently have:

```
    final int[][] myArray = 
        {
              { 1, 2, 5, 4 },
              { 4, 3, 2, 1 },
              { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
              { 8, 7, 6, 5 },
        };

            PrintArray(myArray);
            Analysis(myArray);
}

public static void Analysis(int[][] myArray) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        int sum = sum + myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);


}

public static void PrintArray(final int[][] myArray) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

And it says, "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int[]" at the part with the sum. I am not sure why this would be.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`for-each` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and you need to declare `sum` *before* the loop (so it is visible). And the Java naming conventions would suggest starting with a lower case letter (your method looks like a class).

```
public static void Analysis(int[][] myArray) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int[] arr : myArray) {
        for (int val : arr) {
            sum += val;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a TWO dimensional array. How exactly are you expecting to access it using one indexer?

You can try this:

```
public static void Analysis(int[][] myArray) 
{
    int sum=0; //sum must be initiated BEFORE
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<myArray[i].length;j++)
            sum += myArray[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: can you explain this `myArray.length/l` please. why did you like that?

Comment: it's a double dimensional array. Since l = length of row then myArray/l = number of rows in the whole array. So we loop through the array one row at a time summing all its elements

Comment: What is myArray.length/l??

Comment: l is length of row, myArray.length = length of the array. so myArray.length divided by row length = number of rows you will have to iterate through...

Comment: try your solution with this `final int[][] myArray = { {1, 1}, {1,1}};`, what is the output you get and what is the correct output should be?

Comment: Oh sorry sorry, it should not be there.

Comment: myArray.length gets number of rows. I missed that sorry. Corrected, it works now

Comment: it's working but not the correct result, I suggest move this line `int l = myArray[0].length;` inside of the first `for` loop and modify as this `int l = myArray[i].length;`. you'll see the difference.

Comment: or just modified the second loop without l .. I am really sorry, it's been a time since I used Java

Comment: Thanks, mate. I really appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Your array has **two** dimensions! Thus you need **two** loops iterating both of those dimensions!

```
for (int i.... 
   for (int j=0; j<array[i].length ; j++)  
     sum += array [i] [j] ;
```

You know: very much the same way that you already wrote down your code that prints the array! There is no difference between accessing the array cell for printing.... or for summing them up!

Answer (score 0):

Your "myArray" is a  two dimensions, you need two loop  for it's operation, like this:

```
public static void Analysis(int[][] myArray)
```

`{`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    int sum = sum + myArray[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

`}`

And if i'm not mistaking, your static int[][] myArray is in the main function(?)
i suggest you `final int[][] myArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Analysis(int[][] myArray){
   int sum=0;
   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
      for(int j=0; j< myArray[i].length;j++){
          sum += myArray[i][j];
      }
   }
   System.out.println(sum);
}
```